# Replacing {{string}} within php file

Tags: php, variables, replace

I'm including a file in one of my class methods, and in that file has html + php code. I return a string in that code. I explicitly wrote `{{newsletter}}` and then in my method I did the following:

```
$contactStr = include 'templates/contact.php';
$contactStr = str_replace("{{newsletter}}",$newsletterStr,$contactStr);
```

However, it's not replacing the string. The only reason I'm doing this is because when I try to pass the variable to the included file it doesn't seem to recognize it.

```
$newsletterStr = 'some value';
$contactStr = include 'templates/contact.php';
```

So, how do I implement the string replacement method?

Comment: Does your `include` have a `return`?

Comment: Does including a file trigger the return inside of the page ? Don't think so, you should include the file and then call the function that's returning your string.

Comment: @RelevantUsername ["It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it.  Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function."](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: Accepted answer is great, php code in the template! Wow. -> so question upvoted too!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use PHP as template engine. No need for `{{newsletter}}` constructs.

Say you output a variable `$newsletter` in your template file.

```
// templates/contact.php

<?= htmlspecialchars($newsletter, ENT_QUOTES); ?>
```

To replace the variables do the following:

```
$newsletter = 'Your content to replace';

ob_start();        
include('templates/contact.php');
$contactStr = ob_get_clean();

echo $contactStr;

// $newsletter should be replaces by `Your content to replace`
```

In this way you can build your own template engine.

```
class Template
{
    protected $_file;
    protected $_data = array();

    public function __construct($file = null)
    {
        $this->_file = $file;
    }

    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->_data[$key] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        extract($this->_data);
        ob_start();
        include($this->_file);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

// use it
$template = new Template('templates/contact.php');
$template->set('newsletter', 'Your content to replace');
echo $template->render();
```

The best thing about it: You can use conditional statements and loops (full PHP) in your template right away.

Use this for better readability: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: If you want to protect the included file from variable pollution (*namely `$this`*) you can wrap it in a rebound closure: `call_user_func(Closure::bind(function () { include func_get_arg(0); }, null ), $path);`

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but as far as I understand this example you are just overwriting the variable `$newsletter`, which you have declared before, with the same value.
Since you stil have to echo the variable afterwards the example seems invalid to me and is equivalent to `$x = 'foo'; echo $x;`

Comment: @LeonKramer no, $newsletter will not get overwritten. In the template file it's just echo'd out. It works because $newsletter outside and inside the template are in the same scope. [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Okay, got it now. This short class is very sweet!

Comment: This is beautiful, something I've wanted to know for a long time! Thanks for this.

Comment: Can you explain what is happening? I'm mean if I've whole content/template in a variable then how do I replace in variable using this technique?

Comment: which line does it actually replace the content?

Comment: @FaizanRupani Please try it out and you'll understand it.

Answer (score 17):

This is a code i'm using for templating, should do the trick

```
  if (preg_match_all("/{{(.*?)}}/", $template, $m)) {
      foreach ($m[1] as $i => $varname) {
        $template = str_replace($m[0][$i], sprintf('%s', $varname), $template);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean sprintf('$%s', $$varname) ?

Comment: Actually it looks like it should be sprintf('%s', $$varname)

Answer (score 9):

maybe a bit late, but I was looking something like this.

The problem is that include does not return the file content, and easier solution could be to use file_get_contents function.

```
$template = file_get_contents('test.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

$page = str_replace("{{nombre}}","Alvaro",$template);

echo $page;
```

Answer (score 5):

based on @da-hype

```
<?php
$template = "hello {{name}} world! {{abc}}\n";
$data = ['name' => 'php', 'abc' => 'asodhausdhasudh'];

if (preg_match_all("/{{(.*?)}}/", $template, $m)) {
    foreach ($m[1] as $i => $varname) {
        $template = str_replace($m[0][$i], sprintf('%s', $data[$varname]), $template);
    }
}


echo $template;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use output_buffers together with PHP-variables. It's far more secure, compatible and reusable.

```
function template($file, $vars=array()) {
    if(file_exists($file)){
        // Make variables from the array easily accessible in the view
        extract($vars);
        // Start collecting output in a buffer
        ob_start();
        require($file);
        // Get the contents of the buffer
        $applied_template = ob_get_contents();
        // Flush the buffer
        ob_end_clean();
        return $applied_template;
    }
}

$final_newsletter = template('letter.php', array('newsletter'=>'The letter...'));
```

Comment: if(file_exists($file)){ makes it very, very bad. One should never suppress errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//First, define in the template/body the same field names coming from your data source:
$body = "{{greeting}}, {{name}}! Are You {{age}} years old?";

//So fetch the data at the source (here we will create some data to simulate a data source)
$data_source['name'] = 'Philip';
$data_source['age'] = 35;
$data_source['greeting'] = 'hello';

//Replace with field name
foreach ($data_source as $field => $value) {
    //$body = str_replace("{{" . $field . "}}", $value, $body);
    $body = str_replace("{{{$field}}}", $value, $body);
}

echo $body; //hello, Philip! Are You 35 years old?
```

Note - An alternative way to do the substitution is to use the commented syntax.

But why does using the three square brackets work?

By default the square brackets allow you to insert a variable inside a string.

As in:

```
$name = 'James';
echo "His name is {$name}";
```

So when you use three square brackets around your variable, the innermost square bracket is dedicated to the interpolation of the variables, to display their values:

This `{{{$field}}}` turns into this `{{field}}`

Finally the replacement with `str_replace` function works for two square brackets.

Answer (score -1):

no, don't include for this. `include` is executing php code. and it's return value is the value the included file returns - or if there is no return: 1.

What you want is `file_get_contents()`:

```
// Here it is safe to use eval(), but it IS NOT a good practice.
$contactStr = file_get_contents('templates/contact.php');
eval(str_replace("{{newsletter}}", $newsletterStr, $contactStr));
```

Comment: Using `eval` is very insecure and not allowed in some installations.

Comment: Actually, I was just [reading the docs](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php); the default return value for an `include` statement is `1`, or `false` if the include failed (I'm not sure why it's not boolean `true`, but that's what the docs say).

Comment: @Gustav it's as secure as including a file in this context. You aren't acting on user input. (and eval can not be disabled with vanilla php, it requires an extra extension...)

Comment: @IMSoP thank you, corrected. Thought it would be like a normal function…

Comment: @Gustav he is using eval to... evaluate a script he loaded externally. There is no user input involved and the script would have been just as eval'd in an include. These use cases are the reason `eval` exists in the first place. There is nothing insecure about running your own code. When people tell you eval is bad this is not what they mean at all.

Comment: The difference here is that you are `eval()`ing the code *after* substituting the placeholders, so the contents of `$newsletterStr` can now be crafted to execute arbitrary PHP code if that in turn is not from a trusted source (not specified in the question).

Comment: @IMSoP in his example it was no user input, but a raw string from the file…

Comment: Without the change in order of replacement and evaluation, which doesn't seem to be required by my reading of the question, this amounts to `eval(file_get_contents($filename))`, which would surely do the same thing as `include $filename`

Comment: @bwoebi No, look again, we do not know the real source of `$newsletterStr`, only `$contactStr`. The only line we have is `$newsletterStr = 'some value';`, which is clearly a dummy line as this wouldn't require a placeholder.

Comment: @IMSoP but you are naturally right: no input where the user has direct control of it.

Comment: @bwoebi Eval can be disabled with disable_functions ini-directive. It should be disabled and is on most professional configurations.   @BenjaminGruenbaum @IMSoP file_get_contents works over network, so with this usage you may not only load local arbitrary code but also from anywhere across the Internet, just set `$filename` to an url. The solution to this problem is to use output_buffers.

Comment: @Gustav it cannot be disabled via disable_functions. Try it yourself... include may also work over network

Comment: @Gustav yep, and not so many servers have suhosin installed. (with the directive enabled)