# Using PHP as Template Engine and having a thin Template

Tags: php

I'm using PHP as a template engine per this suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17870094/2081511

I have:

```
$title = 'My Title';
ob_start();
include('page/to/template.php');
$page = ob_get_clean();
```

And on page/to/template.php I have:

```
<?php
echo <<<EOF
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>{$title}</title>
...
EOF;
?>
```

I'm trying to remove some of the required syntax from the template pages to make it easier for others to develop their own templates. What I would like to do is retain the variable naming convention of {$variable} but remove these lines from the template file:

```
<?php
echo <<<EOF
EOF;
?>
```

I was thinking about putting them on either side of the include statement, but then it would just show me that statement as text instead of including it.

Comment: I don't know if what you want to do is possible, short of replacing the {$title} with <?= $title; ?>, but that adds more markup and increases complexity. Have you looked at template systems such as mustache/handlebars, they have a simple syntax {{ title }} for endusers, that are not familiar with php

Comment: Does `page/to/template.php` echo something? What are you doing with `$page`?

Comment: `@bumperbox` in PHP `{$title}` inside double quotes, or heredocs, is really just pointless. `{}` is for situations like `{$obj->title}` or `{$singleDimensionalArray[$number]}`.

Comment: I don't think you even need the heredoc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want a VERY simple templating solution, this might help

```
<?php


$title = 'My Title';

// Instead of including, we fetch the contents of the template file.
$contents = file_get_contents('template.php');

// Clone it, as we'll work on it.
$compiled = $contents;

// We want to pluck out all the variable names and discard the braces
preg_match_all('/{\$(\w+)}/', $contents, $matches);

// Loop through all the matches and see if there is a variable set with that name. If so, simply replace the match with the variable value.
foreach ($matches[0] as $index => $tag) {
  if (isset(${$matches[1][$index]})) {
    $compiled = str_replace($tag, ${$matches[1][$index]}, $compiled);
  }
}

echo $compiled;
```

Template file would look like this

```
<html> <body> {$title} </body> </html>
```