# Importing user data as PHP variables

Tags: php

I have a data file that my users upload with a section comprising of keys and values separated by tabs and line breaks:

```
key     value
city    London
year    1984
```

I import this into a script, then assign PHP variables with the names equal to the value:

```
$key = 'value';
$city = 'London';
$year = 1984;
```

This is used to [populate templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17870094/2081511) that they've also uploaded.

This is my script that assigns to keys and values:

```
$userdata = explode("\n", $file);
foreach($userdata as &$line){
    list($key, $value) = explode("\t", $line);
    $$key = $value;}
```

I'm wondering if this is the best way to assign keys to values, if there are any security precautions I should take such as prevent certain key names, and if there would be a way to make a key equal to an array if the line has multiple tabs.

Comment: I'd just assign the key / value(s) to an array, eg `$props[$key] = $value`

Comment: You may want to look into [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: *"if there are any security precautions I should take such as prevent certain key names"* - Counter-question: What do you foresee as being a security risk? If you're using this to store sensitive information, then you should consider using a database; or place it outside the public root area and safeguard it throuh `.htaccess` if you need to.

Comment: Plus, text files are a lot of work when it comes to managing them.

Comment: The security risk would be having that text file available to the public.

Comment: @PHPglue [*I believe I said that...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43243861/importing-user-data-as-php-variables#comment73558243_43243861) in so many words. Edit: Darn it, made a typo *"throuh"* => *"through"*.

Comment: I feel the question is unclear, maybe even be opinion-based. Edit: You're welcome to ping me; gone playing my guitar ♫

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this:

```
<?php
$filePointer = @fopen($file, 'r');
while($line = fgets($filePointer)){
  $a = preg_split('/\b\s+\b/', $line);
  ${$a[0]} = $a[1];
}
echo "key:$key; city:$city; year:$year;"
?>
```